# Create new TCP Connection for every http requests in Python

Tags: centos, python, tcp

For my college project I am trying to develop a python based traffic generator.I have created 2 CentOS machines on vmware and I am using 1 as my client and 1 as my server machine. I have used IP aliasing technique to increase number of clients and severs using just single client/server machine. Upto now I have created 50 IP alias on my client machine and 10 IP alias on my server machine. I am also using multiprocessing module to generate traffic concurrently from all 50 clients to all 10 servers. I have also developed few profiles(1kb,10kb,50kb,100kb,500kb,1mb) on my server(in /var/www/html directory since I am using Apache Server) and I am using urllib2 to send request to these profiles from my client machine. Here while running my scripts when I monitor number of TCP Connections it is always <50. I want to increase it to say 10000. How do I achieve this? I thought that if a new TCP Connection is established for every new http request, then this goal can be achieved. Am I on right path? If not kindly guide to me correct path.

```
    '''
Traffic Generator Script:

 Here I have used IP Aliasing to create multiple clients on single vm machine. 
 Same I have done on server side to create multiple servers. I have around 50 clients and 10 servers
'''
import multiprocessing
import urllib2
import random
import myurllist    #list of all destination urls for all 10 servers
import time
import socbindtry   #script that binds various virtual/aliased client ips to the script
response_time=[]    #some shared variables
error_count=multiprocessing.Value('i',0)
def send_request3():    #function to send requests from alias client ip 1
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(socbindtry.BindableHTTPHandler3)    #bind to alias client ip1
    try:
    tstart=time.time()
    for i in range(myurllist.url):
        x=random.choice(myurllist.url[i])
        opener.open(x).read()
        print "file downloaded:",x
        response_time.append(time.time()-tstart)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        error_count.value=error_count.value+1
def send_request4():    #function to send requests from alias client ip 2
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(socbindtry.BindableHTTPHandler4)    #bind to alias client ip2
    try:
    tstart=time.time()
    for i in range(myurllist.url):
        x=random.choice(myurllist.url[i])
        opener.open(x).read()
        print "file downloaded:",x
        response_time.append(time.time()-tstart)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        error_count.value=error_count.value+1
#50 such functions are defined here for 50 clients
process=[]
def func():
    global process
    process.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=send_request3))
    process.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=send_request4))
    process.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=send_request5))
    process.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=send_request6))
#append 50 functions here
    for i in range(len(process)):
         process[i].start()
    for i in range(len(process)):
         process[i].join()
    print"All work Done..!!"
         return
start=float(time.time())
func()
end=float(time.time())-start
print end
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for [so]?